# I want to find the image under M of the region R which is the intersection of disks $|z+1|\le 2$ and $|z-1|\le 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $M$ be möbius transformation.

$$M(3^{1/2}i)=\infty$$$$ M(-3^{1/2}i)=0$$$$M(0)=-1$$

I want to find the image under M of the region R which is the intersection of disks $|z+1|\le 2$ and $|z-1|\le 2$

---

I am studying complex analysis. And these questions are difficult for me. I want to learn how to solve such questions. Thank you:)

Comment: There is a way of using the images of the $3$ points to find an explicit form for the Mobius map. Maybe doing that will make it easier. And, BTW, you have $3^{1/2}i)$ twice.

Comment: Currently, you try to let $M$ map $\sqrt{3}\cdot i$ to two different points. One of the two $3^{1/2}i$ probably should get a minus sign.

Comment: Your comments seems so abstract to me. I am new learner. Please can you show more clearly? Thank you so much to all:)

Comment: In your specification of $M$, you have $M(3^{1/2}i) = \infty$ and $M(3^{1/2}i) = 0$. One of the two should probably be $M(-3^{1/2}i) = X$, but which?

Comment: Sorry sorr I can not see it. The second one is minus. Dear @DanielFischer

Comment: Sure. The first thing is to find an explicit formula for the Möbius transformation $M$. Do you know how to go about that?

Comment: Nope! Not exactly know this:(. Can you show? :) @DanielFischer

Comment: To map a point $w$ to zero, the numerator of the Möbius transform must map $w$ to zero, so it must be (a multiple of) $z-w$. To map a point $p$ to $\infty$, the denominator must map $p$ to zero, so that must be a multiple of $z-p$ (I'm assuming that neither $w$ nor $p$ is $\infty$; that would change things a bit). That means you have $c\cdot \dfrac{z-w}{z-p}$. Here, you get $c\cdot \dfrac{z+3^{1/2}i}{z-3^{1/2}i}$. Now pick $c$ such that the remaining requirement is fulfilled. So what explicit formula for $M$ do you get?

Comment: Hmm $c$ should be equal to $1$. Then $M=\frac{z+i\sqrt{3}}{z-i\sqrt{3}}$ Dear @DanielFischer

Comment: Right. Now to find the region the intersection of the two disks is mapped to. To find that, you need to find out to which curves the circular arcs bounding the intersection are mapped. These curves are circular arcs or half-lines, since any Möbius transformation maps (circles and straight lines) to (circles and straight lines). Now, the intersections of the two circles bounding the disks $\lvert z-1\rvert<2$ and $\lvert z+1\rvert<2$ are conveniently $\pm3^{1/2}i$, which are mapped to $0$ and $\infty$, so the bounding arcs will be mapped to straight half-lines. To find which, find the image of

Comment: one point on each of the two arcs. $z=1$ and $z=-1$ are convenient choices, for example.

Comment: Then for $z=1$, the image is $\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Isnt it? Dear @danielFischer

Comment: Indeed. Can you write that in the form $x+iy$ or $re^{i\varphi}$?

Comment: That's, $=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ isnt it?

Comment: From there, what do I need to do? @DanielFischer

Comment: By the way, i found the image just for $z=\pm 1$. Do I need to find the image for other points? If yes, which points? @DanielFischer

Comment: Not quite, it's $-\frac12 + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, the conjugate. So you know the one half-line bounding the region, the half-line from $0$ to $\infty$ passing through $-\frac12 +i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Now find the other half-line by finding the image of $-1$ (you did, you say, check for sign errors, because what you got for $1$, I get for $-1$). Then the intersection of the two disks is mapped to one of the two regions determined by the two half-lines the bounding arcs are mapped to. Which one, you determine by looking where aome point from the interior of the intersection is mapped to.

Comment: That's, the thing I understand is one image is $-1\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ for $z=1$,which is one half-plane. Another image is $-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ for $z=-1$, which is another half-plane. Right? @DanielFischer

Comment: I think that $|z-1|\le 2$ ?? @DanielFischer

Comment: If true, how can I continue to solve the question Dear @DanielFischer

Comment: You have the two rays bounding the region, one is the ray through $M(1) = -\frac12 + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ (since $\lvert 1+1\rvert = 2$, $1$ is in the boundary of one of the two disks), the other goes through $M(-1) = \overline{M(1)}$ ($-1$ is in the boundary of the other disk). So the intersection of the two disks is mapped to one of the two regions of the plane that these two rays bound. You then just need to figure out which one. For example by looking where some point from the interior of the intersection is mapped.

Comment: Then, I need to figüre out $M(1)$, I think @DanielFischer

Comment: Is that a typo? You already know $M(1)$, and $1$ is not in the interior of the intersection.

Comment: Ahh!! Sorry I wrote false:( okay, after there, how to reach the answer?

Comment: Try with $M(0)$.

Comment: $M(0)=-1$ @DanielFischer

Comment: I know. So which of the two regions is it?

Comment: Ah okay $M(-1)$ because $M(0)=-1$ not in the interior of the intersection. @DanielFischer

Comment: $0$ is in the interior of the intersection. That is what matters. The two boundary arcs are mapped to two rays. The region in between, the interior of the intersection, is mapped to one of the two regions between the two rays. Make a sketch to see what goes on.

Comment: Okay, all answer is this?! Thank you so much. I Will study this your answer more carefully:) @DanielFischer

Answer (score 1):

[Without reading 30+ comments]. The points $\pm i\sqrt{3}$ are the intersections of two given circles. Since they go to $0,\infty$, both boundary arcs of the domain are mapped to half-lines from $0$ to $\infty$. Since also $0\mapsto -1$, the segment $L=[-i\sqrt{3},i\sqrt{3}]$ of the imaginary axis is mapped to the negative real axis. Each boundary arc makes angle $\pi/3$ with $L$  (consider the angle between $L$ and a radius of circle, which is $\pi/6$). Since angles are preserved, the images of boundary arcs are at the angle $\pi/3$ to the negative real axis. Thus, the image of the domain is
$$\{re^{i\theta} : r>0, \ 2\pi/3 <\theta<4\pi/3\}$$